# grouping by json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently trying to sort my json objects by project,i have a report object which is holding an application and a project,and i want to get objects grouped by project.This is my json structure of a report object.this structure will be repeated all along the json response: I will receive many reports objects
Is there a library to do that ?

```
{
  "internalId": 60,
  "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
  "project": {
    "internalId": 25,
    "acronym": "IMUPT",
    "label": "IMUP216",
    "comment": "",
    "sap": "58",
    "startingDate": 1488841200000,
    "endingDate": 1553209200000,
    "currency": {
      "internalId": 143,
      "currencyCode": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
    },
    "budget": 250000000,
    "defaultFrReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r_fr.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 2,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 48,
          "languageCode": "fr",
          "languageName": "French"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "defaultEnReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 1,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 41,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "languageName": "English"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "committees": [],
    "subsidies": "No",
    "softSub": "",
    "hardSub": "",
    "validatorPath": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17"
  },
  "application": {
    "internalId": 52,
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "companyName": "PicoSoft",
    "codeName": "43bru532x8av9nxez5mi",
    "subregion": "Ariana",
    "legalForm": "SARL",
    "registrationNumber": "45215455",
    "taxIdentification": "455255656",
    "belongToGroup": false,
    "group": "",
    "corpPurpose": "",
    "hq": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "pu": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "cpFullName": "",
    "cpFunction": "",
    "dc": "",
    "creationDate": 983746800000,
    "startingActivityDate": 983746800000,
    "sc": {
      "amount": 0,
      "national": 0,
      "international": 0
    },
    "mainActivity": {
      "internalId": 53,
      "code": "60",
      "title": "Programming and broadcasting activities",
      "parent": {
            "internalId": 10,
            "code": "J",
            "title": "Information and communication"
          }
        },
        "ipm": "",
        "esit": null,
        "mainMarket": "",
        "employmentNumber": 25,
        "currency": {
          "internalId": 143,
          "currencyCode": "TND",
          "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
        },
        "country": {
          "internalId": 224,
          "a3Code": "TUN",
          "a2Code": "TN",
          "countryName": "Tunisia",
          "nativeCountryName": "Tunisia"
        },
        "reference": "IMUPT17_52"
      },
      "decision": null,
      "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
      "instanceName": "Report"
    },
{
"internalId": 62,
"state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
"project": {
"internalId": 25,
"acronym": "IMUPT",
"label": "IMUP216",
"comment": "",
"sap": "58",
"startingDate": 1488841200000,
"endingDate": 1553209200000,
"currency": {
"internalId": 143,
"currencyCode": "TND",
"currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
},
"budget": 250000000,
"defaultFrReportModelSet": {
"reference": "Sdr9r_fr.pdf",
"comment": "",
"active": false,
"expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"validatorPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"tuPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"bmnPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"locale": {
"internalId": 2,
"language": {
"internalId": 48,
"languageCode": "fr",
"languageName": "French"
}
},
"sections": []
},
"defaultEnReportModelSet": {
"reference": "Sdr9r.pdf",
"comment": "",
"active": false,
"expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"validatorPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"tuPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"bmnPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"locale": {
"internalId": 1,
"language": {
"internalId": 41,
"languageCode": "en",
"languageName": "English"
}
},
"sections": []
},
"committees": [],
"subsidies": "No",
"softSub": "",
"hardSub": "",
"validatorPath": null,
"reference": "IMUPT17"
},
"application": {
"internalId": 54,
"state": "APPROVED",
"companyName": "Telnet",
"codeName": "djw1q2nbtanec4gtzw7b9",
"subregion": "Ariana",
"legalForm": "SARL",
"registrationNumber": "45214455",
"taxIdentification": "55455",
"belongToGroup": true,
"group": "Telnet",
"corpPurpose": "",
"hq": {
"address": "",
"email": "",
"website": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": ""
},
"pu": {
"address": "",
"email": "",
"website": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": ""
},
"cpFullName": "",
"cpFunction": "",
"dc": "",
"creationDate": null,
"startingActivityDate": null,
"sc": {
"amount": 0,
"national": 0,
"international": 0
},
"mainActivity": {
"internalId": 43,
"code": "47",
"title": "Retail trade  except of motor vehicles and motorcycles",
"parent": {
"internalId": 7,
"code": "G",
"title": "Wholesale and retail trade; repair of motor vehicles and motorcycles"
}
},
"ipm": "",
"esit": null,
"mainMarket": "",
"employmentNumber": 520,
"currency": {
"internalId": 143,
"currencyCode": "TND",
"currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
},
"country": {
"internalId": 224,
"a3Code": "TUN",
"a2Code": "TN",
"countryName": "Tunisia",
"nativeCountryName": "Tunisia"
},
"reference": "IMUPT17_54"
},
"decision": null,
"reference": "IMUPT17_62",
"instanceName": "Report"
},
{
"internalId": 61,
"state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
"project": {
"internalId": 25,
"acronym": "IMUPT",
"label": "IMUP216",
"comment": "",
"sap": "58",
"startingDate": 1488841200000,
"endingDate": 1553209200000,
"currency": {
"internalId": 143,
"currencyCode": "TND",
"currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
},
"budget": 250000000,
"defaultFrReportModelSet": {
"reference": "Sdr9r_fr.pdf",
"comment": "",
"active": false,
"expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"validatorPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"tuPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"bmnPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\a21f8c87-eae9-4c04-b00d-41b3087df602\\srd9rTestFR21_08_2017.pdf",
"locale": {
"internalId": 2,
"language": {
"internalId": 48,
"languageCode": "fr",
"languageName": "French"
}
},
"sections": []
},
"defaultEnReportModelSet": {
"reference": "Sdr9r.pdf",
"comment": "",
"active": false,
"expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"validatorPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"tuPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"bmnPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
"locale": {
"internalId": 1,
"language": {
"internalId": 41,
"languageCode": "en",
"languageName": "English"
}
},
"sections": []
},
"committees": [],
"subsidies": "No",
"softSub": "",
"hardSub": "",
"validatorPath": null,
"reference": "IMUPT17"
},
"application": {
"internalId": 53,
"state": "APPROVED",
"companyName": "LB Consulting",
"codeName": "ca9vovl30tg83k6zdunmi",
"subregion": "Ariana",
"legalForm": "SARL",
"registrationNumber": "7850026",
"taxIdentification": "459663",
"belongToGroup": false,
"group": "",
"corpPurpose": "",
"hq": {
"address": "",
"email": "",
"website": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": ""
},
"pu": {
"address": "",
"email": "",
"website": "",
"phone": "",
"fax": ""
},
"cpFullName": "",
"cpFunction": "",
"dc": "",
"creationDate": null,
"startingActivityDate": null,
"sc": {
"amount": 0,
"national": 0,
"international": 0
},
"mainActivity": {
"internalId": 47,
"code": "52",
"title": "Warehousing and support activities for transportation",
"parent": {
"internalId": 8,
"code": "H",
"title": "Transportation and storage"
}
},
"ipm": "",
"esit": null,
"mainMarket": "",
"employmentNumber": 600,
"currency": {
"internalId": 143,
"currencyCode": "TND",
"currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
},
"country": {
"internalId": 224,
"a3Code": "TUN",
"a2Code": "TN",
"countryName": "Tunisia",
"nativeCountryName": "Tunisia"
},
"reference": "IMUPT17_53"
},
"decision": null,
"reference": "IMUPT17_61",
"instanceName": "Report"
},
```

Comment: you can try out http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `i want to get objects grouped by project` - Your javascript object (not JSON) only has one `project` So it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: i have already updated it

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, I think what you want here is to **extract the `project` key from your response object**. And if I am not wrong the object that you have shared is going to be an **array of objects having `project` key property** in most of them.

If above assumptions are what you looking for, then this could be a probable solution.

```js
var data = [{
  "internalId": 60,
  "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
  "project": {
    "internalId": 25,
    "acronym": "IMUPT",
    "label": "IMUP216",
    "comment": "",
    "sap": "58",
    "startingDate": 1488841200000,
    "endingDate": 1553209200000,
    "currency": {
      "internalId": 143,
      "currencyCode": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
    },
    "budget": 250000000,
    "defaultFrReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r_fr.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 2,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 48,
          "languageCode": "fr",
          "languageName": "French"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "defaultEnReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 1,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 41,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "languageName": "English"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "committees": [],
    "subsidies": "No",
    "softSub": "",
    "hardSub": "",
    "validatorPath": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17"
  },
  "application": {
    "internalId": 52,
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "companyName": "PicoSoft",
    "codeName": "43bru532x8av9nxez5mi",
    "subregion": "Ariana",
    "legalForm": "SARL",
    "registrationNumber": "45215455",
    "taxIdentification": "455255656",
    "belongToGroup": false,
    "group": "",
    "corpPurpose": "",
    "hq": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "pu": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "cpFullName": "",
    "cpFunction": "",
    "dc": "",
    "creationDate": 983746800000,
    "startingActivityDate": 983746800000,
    "sc": {
      "amount": 0,
      "national": 0,
      "international": 0
    },
    "mainActivity": {
      "internalId": 53,
      "code": "60",
      "title": "Programming and broadcasting activities",
      "parent": {
        "internalId": 10,
        "code": "J",
        "title": "Information and communication"
      }
    },
    "ipm": "",
    "esit": null,
    "mainMarket": "",
    "employmentNumber": 25,
    "currency": {
      "internalId": 143,
      "currencyCode": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
    },
    "country": {
      "internalId": 224,
      "a3Code": "TUN",
      "a2Code": "TN",
      "countryName": "Tunisia",
      "nativeCountryName": "Tunisia"
    },
    "reference": "IMUPT17_52"
  },
  "decision": null,
  "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
  "instanceName": "Report"
},
{
  "internalId": 60,
  "state": "DIAGNOSIS_APPROVAL",
  "project": {
    "internalId": 5675676,
    "acronym": "IMUPT",
    "label": "IMUP216",
    "comment": "",
    "sap": "58",
    "startingDate": 1488841200000,
    "endingDate": 1553209200000,
    "currency": {
      "internalId": 143,
      "currencyCode": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
    },
    "budget": 250000000,
    "defaultFrReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r_fr.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 2,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 48,
          "languageCode": "fr",
          "languageName": "French"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "defaultEnReportModelSet": {
      "reference": "Sdr9r.pdf",
      "comment": "",
      "active": false,
      "expertPath": "C:\\pmn\\files\\200bba69-1be5-4640-b9e7-47f0d919145f\\srd9rTest.pdf",
      "validatorPath": "",
      "tuPath": "",
      "bmnPath": "",
      "locale": {
        "internalId": 1,
        "language": {
          "internalId": 41,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "languageName": "English"
        }
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    "committees": [],
    "subsidies": "No",
    "softSub": "",
    "hardSub": "",
    "validatorPath": null,
    "reference": "IMUPT17"
  },
  "application": {
    "internalId": 980980908,
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "companyName": "PicoSoft",
    "codeName": "43bru532x8av9nxez5mi",
    "subregion": "Ariana",
    "legalForm": "SARL",
    "registrationNumber": "45215455",
    "taxIdentification": "455255656",
    "belongToGroup": false,
    "group": "",
    "corpPurpose": "",
    "hq": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "pu": {
      "address": "",
      "email": "",
      "website": "",
      "phone": "",
      "fax": ""
    },
    "cpFullName": "",
    "cpFunction": "",
    "dc": "",
    "creationDate": 983746800000,
    "startingActivityDate": 983746800000,
    "sc": {
      "amount": 0,
      "national": 0,
      "international": 0
    },
    "mainActivity": {
      "internalId": 53,
      "code": "60",
      "title": "Programming and broadcasting activities",
      "parent": {
        "internalId": 10,
        "code": "J",
        "title": "Information and communication"
      }
    },
    "ipm": "",
    "esit": null,
    "mainMarket": "",
    "employmentNumber": 25,
    "currency": {
      "internalId": 143,
      "currencyCode": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar"
    },
    "country": {
      "internalId": 224,
      "a3Code": "TUN",
      "a2Code": "TN",
      "countryName": "Tunisia",
      "nativeCountryName": "Tunisia"
    },
    "reference": "IMUPT17_52"
  },
  "decision": null,
  "reference": "IMUPT17_60",
  "instanceName": "Report"
}
]

var project=[];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<Object.entries(data[i]).length;j++){
    checkForData(Object.entries(data[i])[j][0]);
  }
}

console.log(project);

function checkForData(value){
  if(value === "project"){
      project.push(Object.entries(data[i])[j][1]);
   }
}
```